# Oauth2 Strava request failed "bad request"

Tags: oauth-2.0, yii2, strava

i have an Oauth app that im trying to get synced to strava, but am getting the below error:

```
Request failed with code: 400, message: {"message":"Bad Request","errors":[{"resource":"Application","field":"client_id","code":"invalid"}]}
```

the request looks like this:

```
https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?approval_prompt=force&client_id=60232&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyourway.local%2Fuser%2Fsecurity%2Fauth%3Fauthclient%3Dstrava&xoauth_displayname=Your%20Way&state=d7bacc541e1bbc39ec956adbce63e1b15a00a9817367726e663d02e354df883d
```

i get the Strava Authorize screen but then get that error, the client ID does match and the return URI matches the domain in Strava

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out that it was a subsequent call without the required params.